# какой тип данных денежный при добавлении значение

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, access

Добавляю значение в базу данных Access но появляться ошибка "несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора" в Access строка "voznag" тип данных "Денежный".

Какой тип данных надо использовать в Delphi чтобы добавлялась? В edt указал тип данных Text какой тип надо написать вместо этого.

```
qry1.SQL.Add('update reester set voznag='+#39+edt13.Text+#39+
  '  where id='+form1.qry1.FieldByName('id').AsString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте параметры.
Возможно, у вас в Access используется разделитель разрядов отличный от того, который используется в Delphi.

```
qry1.SQL.Add('update reester set voznag= :p1 where id = :p2'; 
qry1.Parameters.ParamByName('p1').Value := StrToFloat(edt13.Text);
qry1.Parameters.ParamByName('p2').Value := form1.qry1.FieldByName('id').Value;
```

Ну и самой собой нужно делать проверку, чтобы в edt13 было именно числовое значение.